# Android Error :trouble writing output: already prepared

Tags: android, eclipse

I imported a project from other's workspace running succusfully there in Api 21 .There is no error in code  after importing it in mine  but as i run the project in eclipse after updating it to android SDK 21 it shows **trouble writing output: already prepared** .There may be some problem in configuration .console please help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about configuration, it´s about old files...

1. Clean Project
2. Refresh Project
3. Build Project.
4. Run